# Arabic letters not read by web3.toUtf8

Tags: solidity, contract-development, web3js

I am using arab letters in bytes32 data stored in a smart contract, when reading the data and converting to utf-8 with `web3.toUtf8()` i get errors like unknown utf character or `Invalid continuation byte` and `Invalid byte index`

If this is the case, how do I fix it?

**EDIT**

This is the code i am using right now ( i fixed it ) :

```
contractInstance.insertPerson(
        web3.fromUtf8(web3.fromDecimal(i+2*i)),
        jsonObj["email"]?jsonObj["email"]:"",
        web3.fromUtf8(jsonObj["FIRST_NAME"]),
        web3.fromUtf8(jsonObj["LAST_NAME"]), 
...
```

this is the code i was using (the one that does not show correct letters):

```
contractInstance.insertPerson(
        web3.fromUtf8(web3.fromDecimal(i+2*i)),
        jsonObj["email"]?jsonObj["email"]:"",
        jsonObj["FIRST_NAME"],
        jsonObj["LAST_NAME"], 
...
```

Comment: How did you encode the data when it was turned into `bytes32`?

Comment: encode ? didn't do anything manually, i had an arabic letter string and i pushed it like any other latin letter string to my mapping. when i read it and convert to utf-8 using web3 i get those errors. am i missing something ?

Comment: Try posting the code for whatever you mean by "pushed it like any other latin letter string to my mapping".